# Spring Boot with Swagger - can't see my JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I can't see my JPARepositories in Swagger-ui. Who can help me? I only see my classes with @RestController Annotation. When I add @RestController to my JpaRepository, it does not help.

Spring Boot Version 1.5.10

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

My JpaRepository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{

    Optional<Product> findByCode(@Param("code") String code);
    List<Product> findByStatusCode(@Param("statusCode") Integer statusCode, Pageable page);

}
```

HTTP call via GET - ProductRepository:

```
/ 20180208132814
// http://localhost:8080/products

{
  "_embedded": {
    "products": [
      {
        "code": "yyyyy",
        "statusCode": 0,
        "mixed_rank": 9999999,
        "offer_count": 0,
        "maxPrice": null,
        "minPrice": null,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
          },
          "product": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
          },
          "offers": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/products/1/offers"
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: Swagger is for documenting rest API's. It won't document the inner workings of your application.

Comment: @BenThurley is correct  Swagger is for documenting REST API. if you have any specific problem with that post it?

Comment: I can call my JpaRepository with HTTP and GET. In my opition JpaRepository is not only for inner access. The HAL Browser shows the links, but swagger not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://reflectoring.io/documenting-spring-data-rest-api-with-springfox/ it was so easy :)

Comment: What was the solution? Adding "@Api" on top of your repository class?